# CMAKE create directory with write access

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, copy

I'm using `CMAKE` to build my C++ project. At the end of the build, I want to copy the `dlls` to a directory one level up. I use the below commands to achieve that:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${LIB_TARGET}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/win64/dll
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:${LIB_TARGET}> ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/win64/dll/.
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${LIB_TARGET}> ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/win64/dll/.
    )
```

I then get a `setLocal` error when it tries to copy the `dll` to the `win64` directory. Seems like the copy fails because the `win64` directory is `read-only`. How can I make the output build directory `win64` writable?

Thanks!

Comment: The third command doesn't look right: you're telling it to copy a directory, but `-E copy` can only copy files. Is this perhaps the source of your error?

Comment: Actually, it seems to work even with this command - but not all the time. If I delete the `win64` folder and do a clean build, it seems happy. But a normal build fails..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the DLL was in use when I ran CMAKE to build my project. I closed the application which was using the DLL and it worked